# Design solution for One web application multiple clients

Tags: jakarta-ee, design-patterns, architecture

I am working on a web application which in future will be used by multiple clients. so wanted to decide on what all design problems i need to take care of so that i should be flexible enough.

every client will have some customization in the UI and look and feel.
might be having small customization in the business logic how i can.
provide different URL's for same application to each of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Start with MVC to manage separation of concerns.
Not entirely sure about the second part of your question about URL